# Double tap gesture on parent view and single tap gesture on child view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a double tap `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a view and a single tap `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it's child view.

```
    let parentGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "doubleTappedParent")
    parentGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    parentView.addGestureRecognizer(parentGR)

    let childGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTappedChild")
    childGR.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    childView.addGestureRecognizer(childGR)
```

When I double tap the child view, both actions are triggered. How can I have it such that the single tap gesture "cancels" the double tap gesture?

Comment: Use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to discard one when other is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relationship between recognizers using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`. For instance:

```
gr2.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(gr)
```

Update: as @tumber033 mentioned in the comment, in his example `gr2` and `gr` should be swapped, so that there should be

```
parentGR.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(childGR)
```